# When to use GWT ensureInjected()?

Tags: css, gwt

I created a few styles into a CSSResource and it works well whether I use

```
GWT.<MyResources>create(MyResources.class).myStyles().ensureInjected();
```

or not.

Could anyone shed a light on this and explain when to use ensureInjected or not?

Thank you!
Daniel

Answer (score 8):

As Christian said, *inside* the UiBinder `ui.xml` file you don't have to worry about invoking `ensureInjected()`, the following XML statements do the job:

```xml
<ui:with field='myStyle' type='com...MyStyle'/>
```

```xml
<div class='{myStyle.redBorder}'/>
```

Of course this is assuming that there is somewhere a `MyStyle` interface defined:

```
public interface MyStyle {
    public String redBorder();
}
```

Now I agree with you that things get annoying when you need to manipulate the `CssResource` extension *outside* of UiBinder templates. Precisely because you have to take care of invoking `ensureInjected()` somewhere before using the `MyStyle` instance with your widgets.

I personally use GIN to inject instances of extensions of `CssResource` whenever I need them.That way you can implement a custom GIN provider ensuring that `ensureInjected()` is called on the `CssResource` before injecting it.
There are three steps involved there:

- Create an interface for `MyStyle` alongside with a CSS file.
  **MyStyle.java**

  ```
  public interface MyStyle {
      public String redBorder();
  }
  ```
- **MyStyle.css**

  ```
  .redBorder { border: 1px solid red; }
  ```
- Expose it through a `ClientBundle` extension.
  **Resources.java**

  ```
  public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {
      @Source("MyStyle.css")
      public MyStyle style();
  }
  ```
- Configure a GIN provider method to inject your instances of `MyStyle`.
  **ClientModule.java**

  ```
  public class ClientModule extends AbstractGinModule {
      @Override
      protected void configure() {
      //...
      }

      @Provides MyStyle createStyle(final Resources resources) {
          MyStyle style = resources.style();
          style.ensureInjected();
          return style;
      }
  }
  ```

We smoothly inject the `Resources` instance here above, which means no more hassle of a static accessor calling `GWT.<Resources>create(Resources.class)` anywhere, it just all happens through the GIN injection.

Having done that you can inject your instances of `MyStyle` when you need them.
For example (in some MVP context):

```
private Widget widget;

@Inject
public SomeView(final MyStyle style) {
    //...
    widget = uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);
    widget.addStyleName(style.redBorder());
}
```

Comment: Do you really need the `@Inject` annotation on `createStyle()`?

Comment: Should ClientMOdule.java refer to `MyStyle` instead of `Style`?

Answer (score 6):

Good question - one situation that comes to my mind is when you want to use styles from some global stylesheet in a UiBinder template - then you need to call `ensureInjected` to... ensure the styles are indeed injected when you are referencing them (the "local" UiBinder styles, that you define in xml are automagically injected).

You can see this used as such in the [Mail example](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/mail/src/com/google/gwt/sample/mail/client/Mail.java#59):

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    // Inject global styles.
    GWT.<GlobalResources>create(GlobalResources.class).css().ensureInjected();

    // Create the UI defined in Mail.ui.xml.
    DockLayoutPanel outer = binder.createAndBindUi(this);

    // ...rest of the code
}
```

Note how `ensureInjected` is called before binding the UI.

This is the only situation I know that warrants using `ensureInjected`, but maybe I missed something.

Comment: Yes, I understood this as well but: I am using a global css file and it works well whether I use ensureInjected or not. This is the mystery I am try to solve.

Answer (score 6):

The rule is easy: you have to call `ensureInjected()` explicitly, unless the `CssResource` is being generated from an `<ui:style>` in a UiBinder template (because most of the time you won't have a handle on the generated `CssResource`.
Specifically, `<ui:with>` provides no special treatment for `CssResource`s.

Also, a few widgets take a specific `ClientBundle` as argument to a constructor (such as `CellTable`), they will then call `ensureInjected()` on the `CssResource` they use.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on `ui:with`. Does ensureInjected() have to be called for that or not?

Comment: Because `ui:with` does nothing special regarding `CssResource`, it means that, yes, you have to call `ensureInjected()` _manually_, explicitly.

Comment: is there any way to have the CssResource be auto included when its called from uiBinder?

Comment: No. Declare it has a `@UiField` in your Java counterpart (with the same name as the `field` attribute of the `<ui:with>`) so you can call `ensureInjected()` after the `createAndBindUi()`.

Comment: What about if I do `<ui:style src=..." />`? Also, are you saying that the accepted answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5536378/49153) is wrong? Its saying that `ui:with` does auto include the css

Comment: As I said in the answer, `<ui:style>`automatically injects the stylesheet, because there might not even be an explicit Java interface for it. And there's no accepted answer. The most up-voted one is not wrong though, it says “you have to take care of invoking `ensureInjected()` somewhere before using the `MyStyle` instance with your widgets.”

Comment: The most upvoted one (that I linked to) says this: `inside the UiBinder ui.xml file you don't have to worry about invoking ensureInjected(), the following XML statements do the job:

<ui:with field='myStyle' type='com...MyStyle'/>`. Isn't that saying that by doing `ui:with`, it takes care of injecting the css?

Comment: Note that I'm only talking about using the cssResource within the uiBinder template, not in the java code.

Comment: It's misleading, but the phrase I quoted makes it clearer. I think what the author wanted to say is that you won't call `ensureInjected()` from within the `ui.xml`. Also note that the `<ui:with>` has to be on the `ClientBundle` (not the `CssResource`) unless you use a `@UiField(provided=true)` or `@UiFactory`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it much clearer. One question, if I want to do `ui:style` and my css resource was located in a different package, e.g if my uiBinder xml file is in `com.foo.view.someUi.ui.xml`, and I wanted to include `com.foo.css.SomeCssResource` via `ui:style src=..`, how would I give the path to `SomeCssResource?`

Comment: `ui:style src=` links to a CSS file, not a `CssResource` (you can use `type=` for that, it'll then generate an interface the `inherits` the on you name). The path can be either relative (using `../`) or, starting with GWT 2.5.0, absolute (starting with a `/`). See https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7230

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I'll give you a bounty since you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you use UiBinder the call to ensureInjected is provided by the tag ui:with. For any other css you are using in a client bundle (i.e. legacy css excluded) and that are not declared in a ui:with block, you have to call ensureInjected explicitly.

Comment: I'm using UiBinder exclusively, but for me, it isn't provided...I had to call it explicitly.