# ClientBundle don't load the ImageResource

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, clientbundle

I try to use the ClientBundle implementation to manage my Images to a large File and minimize the HTTP-Requests.

I put  in my gwt.xml

Generate the ClientBundle

public interface ResourceBundle extends ClientBundle {

```
public static final ResourceBundle INSTANCE = GWT.create(ResourceBundle.class);

@Source("tiles/smiley.png")
ImageResource smiley();
```

}

The Image would be found, no errors.

Here is the code

@Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {

```
    CLogger.log("Start Engine");

    int width = 800;
    int height = 600;

    Canvas canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();
    canvas.setWidth(width + "px");
    canvas.setHeight(height + "px");
    canvas.setCoordinateSpaceWidth(width);
    canvas.setCoordinateSpaceHeight(height);
    Context2d c = canvas.getContext2d();

    Image img = new Image(ResourceBundle.INSTANCE.smiley());
    img.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
            CLogger.log(event.getSource() + " loaded");
        }
    });
    CLogger.log("Visible: " + img.isVisible());

    c.drawImage((ImageElement) new Image(ResourceBundle.INSTANCE.smiley()).getElement().cast(), 0, 0);

    RootPanel.get().add(canvas);
```

}

I create a simple Canvas and set the size to 800x600. I create a new Context2D Object to draw the Image at the Context and add the Canvas to the RootPanel.

The logs shows:

[20:10:21.676] - Start Engine
[20:10:21.851] - Visible: true
[20:10:21.853] - http://127.0.0.1:8888/engine/7D39451825E9952050F44A6B8E2E15F3.cache.png

The Image exists under the logged URL so everything looks fine. But the Image would not be draw or it would draw but not display.

Anybody an idea?

I thought the ClientBundle loads the Images as the start in the backend. So if I get an Instance every Image/Css and others fill be loaded?

Regars Markus

Answer (score 0):

Image contents aren't guaranteed to be loaded synchronously.  Depending on the capabilities of the browser and the size of the image data, the resource may be stored as a standalone file, which appears to be the case that you're describing (i.e. `cache.png`).  Does a formulation like this make any difference?

```
final Image img = new Image(ResourceBundle.INSTANCE.smiley());
img.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {
  public void onLoad(LoadEvent e) {
    c.drawImage((ImageElement) img.getElement());
  }
}
RootPanel.get().add(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use CSSResources and ImageBundles outside of UiBinder you have to make sure that the stlyesheet and images are injected properly.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406687/when-use-gwt-ensureinjected/5536378#5536378) for more information.