# How to add formatting to a Radio Button in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

I need to format the text alongside a particular Radio Button in gwt, how do I change the formatting for that particular Radio Button ?

If there is a particular way to do that through java code itself, I don't want to edit xml or directly add css scripts.

Also I tried using something like this :

rb.addStyleName(Resources.INSTANCE.cssElements().red());
                            rb.addStyleName(Resources.INSTANCE.cssElements().boldfont());

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I did Call ensureInjected().

The following Code did the Job for me :-

```
rb.getElement().getStyle().setColor("blue");
rb.getElement().getStyle().setFontWeight(FontWeight.BOLD);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you call `Resources.INSTANCE.cssElements().ensureInjected()`?

See this question: [When to use GWT ensureInjected()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406687)